# Identify Whether Document is Published Or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, splistitem

I have to call SP search Api for documents in document Library applying filter for only bring such documents which are published and having specific content type .

Is there any specific property for the items in document library which determines whether the document is Published Or not  using javascript 
.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your looking for is this:

using rest

> var value = SP.File.get_checkOutType()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244900.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.checkouttype.aspx

***Example***

```
$.ajax({url: "/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + pageUrl  + "')/checkOutType",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
        success: function(data) {

              switch(data.d.CheckOutType) {
                 case 0:
                     console.log('The file is checked out for editing on the server.');
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     console.log('The file is checked out for editing on the local computer.');
                   break;
                 default:
                     console.log('The file is not checked out.');
               }

        }
});
```

Comment: how can i use it in query string for search api which gives me only published documents

Comment: ok, what do you want to do with the result? if you want to simply display the data based on a query why not use a filer app http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/396c42/retrieve-checked-out-documents-from-the-whole-site-collectio/ or do you want to specifically use the search JS api as your using the data elsewhere?